# AttributeError Py

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium4

New to Python Selenium.

I am trying to create an script to login to my home router and press the button restart.

Running to error, when trying to login to the router, can some on guide on my mistake here.

below is the code and also attaching the .[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3KZs.jpg)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)

PASSWORD = 'testtes'

login_page = 'http://192.168.2.1/login.html'

driver.get(login_page)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

Below is the error I am getting.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pyhton\index.py", line 14, in 
> driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
> AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

getting this error now.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\pyhton\index.py", line 13, in 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 856, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 429, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@placeholder='Password']"}

Answer (score 2):

Probably you are using Selenium 4. if so, `find_element_by_xpath` and all the others `find_element_by_*` methods are not supported by Selenium 4, you have to use the new syntax and add an essential import, as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver_service = Service(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driver_service)

PASSWORD = 'testtes'

login_page = 'http://192.168.2.1/login.html'

driver.get(login_page)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

Comment: no did not work. Instead gave some other error, added the new error to my post

Comment: Now, it's definitely another, new issue. I guess I know what is the problem now. Please share the HTML of that page, not only the single element, you are trying to access. As text, not as a picture and I will try help you more. Also, preferably ask a new question for that since this is a really different issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Password']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
```

Comment: no did not work.  added the new error to my post

Comment: According to the error code there is no element with that xPath. Double check your xPath to make sure it is correct!